# SAS: execute sql query strings out of a table?

Tags: sas

If I have a table containing sql query strings like this (column `query`)

```
id  query                                 n
——————————————————————————————-—————————————
1   select count(*) from tab where x=...
2   select count(*) from tab where x=...
...
```

In SAS is there a way to save the results of these queries in another column `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun - an approach using only proc sql:

```
data queries;
input id :8. query :$100.;
infile datalines dsd;
datalines;
1,select count(*) as count from sashelp.class where sex = 'F'
2,select count(*) as count from sashelp.class where sex = 'M'
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select catx(' ','select ', id, ' as id,', substr(query, 7)) into :code
    separated by ' union all ' 
    from queries;
  create table want as
    &code;
quit;
```

This will only work as long as the total combined length of all your queries fits within the maximum allowed length of a single macro variable. If in doubt, check the value of the MVARSIZE system option.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly well! Just a short follow-up question: What if the `id`-Variable is a string-variable instead of numeric? In my case the values have leading zeros (e.g. '00301'), which got then cut off.

Comment: In that case input them as character using a character informat (e.g. `:$5.`) or apply a numeric format that displays leading zeros (e.g. `z5.`).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by calling a macro within a data step, but depending on how the query is written, you'll have to call it in a sub-query in `proc sql`.

```
%macro run_query(q,id);

/* This section expects that your original query assigns the alias 'count' to the result value */
proc sql noprint;
select count into: count * This assigns the result count into a macro variable count;
from (
&q.) a;
quit;

data want;
set want;
if id=&id. then result = &count.;
run;

%mend;
```

At this point we have the macro `run_query` which takes the query, and id as inputs. Next, we will copy the dataset and then iterate through the original dataset updating each result based on the `id`.

```
data want;
set have;
run;

data _null_;
set have;
call execute(%nrstr(%run_query('||query||','||id||'))');
run;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont really get it to work: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340229/sas-run-sql-query-using-a-macro

Answer (score 1):

If all the queries have a result set of one row & one column, you are dealing with a scalar result which can be placed in a data set variable.

Interaction features to use:

- `dosubl`, execute a separate SAS code block ***while a STEP is running***. A `Proc SQL` query in this case.

  - > The [DOSUBL](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p09dcftd1xxg1kn1brnjyc0q93yk.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) function enables the **immediate execution** of SAS code...
    > DOSUBL executes code in a different SAS executive (*known as a side session*)
- `into :macro-variable`, store result in a macro variable
- `symget`, retrieve result from macro environment

If you are querying the same native SAS table over and over again, you might consider including:

- `sasfile`, opening the data set into memory so disk i/o occurs only once when querying the table repeatedly

**Example**

The queries, as stated in the question, do NOT include an `INTO` clause.  On the presumption that each query does not have `INTO` AND has a single scalar result, the `INTO` clause can be introduced into the query string via `TRANWRD`.

```
data have;
  input;
  query = _infile_;
datalines;
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'F'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'F' and 'K'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'K' and 'O'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'O' and 'S'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'S' and 'ZZ'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'K'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'O'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'S'
select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'ZZ'
;

sasfile sashelp.class open;

data want;
  set have;

  * tweak 'presumed to be scalar' query;

  length into_query $1000; drop into_query;
  into_query = tranwrd (query, 'from', 'into :scalar_result from');

  rc = dosubl('proc sql noprint; ' || into_query);

  query_result = symget('scalar_result');
run;

sasfile sashelp.class close;

ods listing; proc print; run;
```

`have` proc print

```
                                                                                   query_
Obs                                  query                                   rc    result

 1     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'F'      0       4
 2     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'F' and 'K'      0       8
 3     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'K' and 'O'      0       2
 4     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'O' and 'S'      0       3
 5     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'S' and 'ZZ'     0       2
 6     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'K'      0      12
 7     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'O'      0      14
 8     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'S'      0      17
 9     select count(*) from sashelp.class where name between 'A' and 'ZZ'     0      19
```